# How to auto update app variable based on it's state on web server

Tags: java, android

I am building a multi cashier supermarket app who is sharing the same database and I need instant changes In the product info(Quantity), for example, if cashier A served product, cashier B should know this change and know the new value of this product quantity instantly.

Comment: Okay, what is your question?

Comment: `instantly` won't happen, as delivering information, and connection quality may *delay* or even *fail* this information delivery sometimes. But probably what you are looking for is push notifications.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So what should I do to prevent cashier A from selling a product which is already sold by cashier B, have any idea?

Comment: @nbokmans What should I do to prevent cashier A from selling a product which is already sold by cashier B?

Comment: synchronize it on the server-side, for example - make it transaction-based

Answer (score 0):

You can use real-time database like `firebase` or create `service` which observe this variable states change

Comment: I think it's about services, But how can I start with it?

Comment: Using `service` also will make some delay, as it will make `web-service` call to check this value depending on the time you define, I think you should try `firebase`